# Force evaluate floating version packages with lock file via MsBuild / csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I want to use the Locking dependencies of Nuget (>= 4.9), so I can have automatic package update during dev phase and fixed version during release build.

I enabled the lock file mode, so I now have a `packages.lock.json` file.

The problem is that when I have floating version of package references in the project file like:

```
<PackageReference Include="My.Nuget.Package" Version="1.0.*" />
```

The restore package via Visual Studio Build does not update to new packages version anymore. This behavior appeared after I activated the lock file.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#locking-dependencies) describes the `--force-evaluate` option with `dotnet.exe`, that works well but I want to do this directly with an MsBuild option in the csproj.

By checking the NuGet Client code, it seems that a `RestoreForceEvaluate` option exists in Msbuild NuGet.targets but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> By checking the NuGet Client code, it seems that a RestoreForceEvaluate option exists in Msbuild NuGet.targets but I have no idea how to use it.

I am afraid we could not do that at this moment. According to the nuget wiki,

[Enable repeatable package restore using lock file](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Enable-repeatable-package-restore-using-lock-file#restore-command-line-options):

[image]

There is no such MSBuild equivalent option for option `--force-evaluate`, so we could not use `--force-evaluate` directly with an MsBuild option in the csproj.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but where is Re-evaluate and Restore?

Comment: @maxence51, This is a preparing feature. It will appear on a later version. I am sorry that I mentioned it too early, I have updated the answer. I hope this does not bring you too much trouble.

Comment: Ok thank you Leo, I will deal with the CLI until this will appears in Visual Studio.